# Erro ao gerar XML de um banco MySQL

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estou precisando gerar XML à partir de um banco de dados MySQL. Estou utilizando banco de dados MySQL com PHP (que fique claro que sou novato em PHP, o que fiz foi com um vídeo do Youtube ([esse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MJz4y2Ve44)) e muito pouco do que sei).

```
<?php

    define('HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1');
    define('USERNAME', 'root');
    define('PASSWORD', null);
    define('DATABASE', 'cadastro');
    define('CHARSET' , 'utf8');


    include_once("conexao.php");

    $sql = 'select id, descricao, margem, custo, estoque from produtos';

    $resultado = mysqli_query(DBConnect(), $sql) or die (mysqli_error(DBConnect()));

    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->formatOutput = true;

    $produtos = $xml->createElement=('Produtos');

    while($dados = mysqli_fetch_object($resultado))
    {
        $item = $xml->createElement('Item');
        $descricao = $xml->createElement('descricao', $dados->descricao);
        $margem = $xml->createElement('margem', $dados->margem);
        $custo = $xml->createElement('custo', $dados->custo);
        $estoque = $xml->createElement('estoque', $dados->estoque);

        $item->appendChild($descricao);
        $item->appendChild($margem);
        $item->appendChild($custo);
        $item->appendChild($estoque);

        $produtos->appendChild($item);
    }

    $xml->appendChild($produtos);

    header('content-type: text/xml');
    print $xml->saveXML();

?>
```

O erro que dá:

***Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function appendChild() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_fundamental\2.PHPparaXML\config.php:35 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_fundamental\2.PHPparaXML\config.php on line 35***

(A linha 35 que é dita no erro é justamente: `$produtos->appendChild($item);`)

Gostaria de ajuda pra finalizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro significa que você está chamando uma função de uma variável que não é um objeto.

Isso acontece porque você está criando o elemento de forma errada aqui:

```
$produtos = $xml->createElement=('Produtos');
```

O certo é:

```
$produtos = $xml->createElement('Produtos');
```